# how to create django multiple user types

Tags: django, django-3.0

I am working on a project where I need to have 3 types of Users.

```
Admin
Vendor
Customer
```

My first approach to this problem was to define all models by sub-classing the AbstractUser model

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Vendor(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

so the question is do i need to craete a UsermManager for every usertype model  ?

Comment: Maybe you can use `groups` in `User` model.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups

Comment: but every user have his own attributes   could that work ?

Comment: Then the best way to do it (in my opinion) is to define your 3 models (real ones, not abstract ones), and to define a [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) relation to the default User. You also could do it with the [Multi Table Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) paradigm in Django, which does exactly what you want (it defines OneToOne relations underneath).

Comment: great , what about the user manager should i make a user manager for every user model or what ?

Comment: What do you mean with user manager ? Each of your other user models will be linked to the User model of django. So they will all use the same model for authentication,... all the extra information will be on your Vendor, Customer, and Admin.

Comment: i mean like the BaseUserManager to createsuper users and so on ?

Comment: It's really up to you I think. You could use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/). And you can do it the way you want. 1) You create a User and you chose its type in the form, then with a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, since you've chosen the type of the User you want to create, you create it and link it to the User (all of this in the Signal). OR 2) You create the type of User you want with a specific form (Admin, Vendor or Customer) and you also create a User that you link to it.

Comment: Or even without signals.. You can do it in the view that handles your form.

Comment: so one BaseUserManager for all the user models ?

Comment: I can't tell you. This really depends on your needs. I've already done 2 projects with Django so far and I've never written a Manager on my own, whereas I extended the User model too. So without extra information, code, goals you want to achieve or whatever, I'm not able to tell you. What do you want to do / add in your manager ?

Comment: i would like to define a function to create a staff_user , superuser ......

Comment: If you only have to do that, I guess you can do all of them in the User one.

Answer (score 0):

As I said into a comment, the best way to achieve what you want is to use the [Multi Table Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) paradigm in Django. It defines [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) relations underneath so you could do it on your own.

Extending the User model is also explained [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) (official Django documentation) and it is done the way I told you (with OneToOne relations).